# Arrays.toString() prints String with [] and , ---any alternative?

Tags: java, tostring

while programming i accepted a string ...changed it to char array using

```
string.toCharArray()
```

...and had to change it back to string (because i am using recurion and have to pass the string as argument each time)..how to do this..???

i tried using `array.toString()`...but it passes gibberis..beginning with @....then i searched here and found out about `Arrays.toString()`.....but learned that it does indeed convert it to string but adds [] and , ...i need the original string....how to go about this...heres part of the code..

```
   public String replace(String str, char ch) {

    if(count ==0){
        Scanner sc2= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the character to be  replaced with ");
         c2 =sc2.next().charAt(0);
         len=str.length();

     }
    arr=str.toCharArray();
    if(arr[count]==ch){
        arr[count]=c2;
        }
    count++;
    str=Arrays.toString(arr);                 //  Problem


    if(count<len)
        temp=replace(str,ch);
    else
        temp=str;
    return temp;

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[]) ... ignoring that there's no need to use a `char[]` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
String chString = new String(myCharArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert a `char[]` to a `String`, then just use `new String(array)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this array to String constructor:

```
String original = new String(arr);
```